# gulp doesn't see folder in pipeline with gulp-pug and gulp-plumber

Tags: gulp

I'm using `gulp=4.0.2`, `gulp-plumber=1.2.1`, `gulp-pug=5.0.0`. My file structure is roughly

```
gulpfile.js
└── src/pug/pages
    ├── contact.pug
    ├── index.pug
    └── projects
        └── project.pug
```

My `gulpfile.js` contains

```js
import gulp from 'gulp';
const { src, dest, watch: __watch, parallel, series } = gulp;
import pug from 'gulp-pug';
import plumber from 'gulp-plumber';

function views() {
  return (
    src('src/pug/pages/**/*.pug')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(pug({
        pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(dest('./'))
    .pipe(__reload())
  )
}

const watch = parallel(watchTask, reload);
const build = series(parallel(styles, scripts, html, views));

const _build = build;
export { _build as build };
const _default = watch;
export { _default as default };
```

and when I run

```
gulp
```

it creates `index.html` but it doesn't create `projects/project.html`, what I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what happened is that I must have run `gulp build` before and I forgot about it and then I created new pages when I had `src('src/pug/pages/*.pug')` and it worked but then I didn't know if it works for folders so I added `**/` (`src/pug/pages/**/*.pug` and got confused. `gulp` alone runs a default task which doesn't run `views` function so it doesn't create HTML pages. In my case `gulp build` creates them.

The solution is to run

```
gulp build
```